# Why does this hexadecimal value gets different decimal value?

Tags: java

I want to dynamically set an integer variable using a hexadecimal value, but when I use `Integer.parse(hexValue, 16)` it gets a different value from setting as `int a = 0x04A7D488`

For example:

```
int a = 0x04A7D3B8;
System.out.println("a = " + a); // prints 78107576

int b = Integer.parseInt("04A7D3B8", 16); 
System.out.println("b = " + b); // prints 78107784
```

Why do I get different values? How can I dynamically set variable `a` with value `0x04A7D3B8`?

**Note:** I've discovered that this error is only happening with Java SDK 1.8.0_171.

Comment: [Can't reproduce.](https://ideone.com/UzXfwm)

Comment: @shmosel Have you tried using Eclipse with JDK 8?

Comment: What... what version of Java are you running? `java -version` Also unable to repro on 1.8.0_191

Comment: Yes. The result is the same.

Comment: @MattClark I am using Eclipse with JDK 1.8.0_171

Comment: 78107784 in hexadecimal is `04a7d488`.

Comment: There's something very strange with this SDK. I've tried in repl.it and I am getting the same results. But in this machine it gets different values!

Comment: @MattClark I will upgrade my SDK to _191. Thanks to everybody!

Comment: @MattClark I'm seeing the same output: https://imgur.com/a/ozixgs3

Comment: @MattClark try it with this `long a = 0xFD8914EC;` and `long b = Long.parseLong("FD8914EC", 16);`, you will get `-41347860` and `4253619436`, respectively.

Comment: @shmosel Take a look at https://repl.it/@WagnerShimatai/GPSJavaHexa I can't understand why it's getting different values...

Comment: I know that `F` at the beggining of hexa value means `negative`. But why do I get so different values?

Comment: The 0xf....... case is due to sign extension from int to long.  Long literals should be suffixed with 'L'.

Comment: Because `0xFD8914EC` is an integer. Try `0xFD8914ECL`.

Comment: Post your answer as an answer rather than editing your question, please. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Solution**

I was trying to convert a negative integer value using `Long.parseLong` or `Integer.parseInt`, but the correct solution is using `Integer.parseUnsignedInt("FD8914EC");`

In my tests, the value `FD8914EC` was converting to `-41347860` (declaring as `long a = 0xFD8914EC`) or `4253619436` (declaring as `long b = Long.parseLong("FD8914EC", 16);`), but you have always to use `Integer.parseUnsignedInt` (the result will be negative if the hexadecimal value starts with `F`).